# On importing yaml config file , application.yml is getting overriden

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am importing a yaml config file onto my main ServerConfig class. However when I am bringing up the server, it is setting the new yaml file as the applicationConfig & ignoring the properties set in application.yml. Ideally it should append the new config but without ignoring the base application.yml. How can I fix this?

Main config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@Import({
        NewPropertiesConfig.class
        })
@EnableConfigurationProperties({...})
public class ServerConfig extends AbstractConfig  {
...
}
```

NewPropertiesConfig.class

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(
    value = {"classpath:abc-client.yaml"},
    factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class
)
public class NewPropertiesConfig {
    public NewPropertiesConfig() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of the question, we are trying to load properties from two separate property files.

Based on the provided code example, the specified properties file is `abc-client.yml`, thus Spring will load properties from that file.

If we want Spring to load properties from multiple files, then we need to specify each file to use.

I have never tried loading properties from multiple yaml files, but here is how I do it with multiple .properties files.

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@PropertySource("classpath:abc-client.properties")
public class NewPropertiesConfig {
    //...
}
```

In the event of a name collision, the property from the last file wins, which is the desired behavior based on my understanding of the question. Not sure if this also works with yaml.